# Fail to apply multiple git filters on one file

Tags: git, filter, git-config, gitattributes

I have the following `.gitattributes`:

```
src/boot/firebaseConfig.js filter=updateFirebaseConfig
```

and the following `.git/config`:

```
[filter "updateFirebaseConfig"]
        smudge = smudgeFirebaseConfig.sh %f
        clean = cleanFirebaseConfig.sh %f
```

This is my `/usr/local/bin/cleanFirebaseConfig.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x
sed -i -e "s/base64string/{FIREBASE_KEY}/g" $1
sed -i -e "s/url.firebaseapp.com/{AUTH_DOMAIN}/g" $1
sed -i -e "s/https:\/\/url.firebaseio.com/{CONN_STR}/g" $1
sed -i -e "s/url\.appspot\.com/{STORAGE_BUCKET}/g" $1
sed -i -e "s/project/{PROJECT_ID}/g" $1
sed -i -e "s/idstring/{APP_ID}/g" $1
```

I am on MacBook using BASH. There are 2 problems I encounter:

(1) It cleans the file `src/boot/firebaseConfig.js` on my local repository - replacing the values with the placeholder which is NOT intended behaviour.

(2) The clean operation is performed when I `git add` the changed file `src/boot/firebaseConfig.js` and at the end the file still shows up as changed and unstaged and I have to add again - DUPLICATE `git add` due to git changing the local file.

(3) When I browse the remote repository, this file is empty - removed.

Any idea and insight is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
sed \
-e "s/base64string/{FIREBASE_KEY}/g" \
-e "s/url.firebaseapp.com/{AUTH_DOMAIN}/g" \
-e "s/https:\/\/url.firebaseio.com/{CONN_STR}/g" \
-e "s/url\.appspot\.com/{STORAGE_BUCKET}/g" \
-e "s/projectid/{PROJECT_ID}/g" \
-e "s/appid/{APP_ID}/g" $1
```

Comment: Smudge and clean filters *must operate on the data passing through the filter* (on its standard input, and going to its standard output), not on any particular file. Remove the `$1`. The `%f` argument is available only so that you can know what the name of the file will be in the future: at the time the filter is operating, that file may not even exist yet.

Comment: The code snippet provided here works for me now. Do I need to remove the `$1` parameter?

Comment: Yes. As it is, the code will sometimes work (by chance) and sometimes fail.